Chrome memory profiling
I am doing memory profiling for a large web application. One screen is specifically very large in terms of memory consumption. I want to fine the largest JS memory objects and try releasing them to gain memory back. I have created a memory snapshot, but I dont see how I would identify such objects. Can someone help with the right direction?
Thanks
